# URL Routes With Same Pattern But Different Named Segments

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

So let's say I have the following 2 routes defined for my cool new ASP.NET MVC application:

- `{controller}/{action}/{id}`
- `{controller}/{action}/{page}`

Both routes have the same exact pattern except for the last named segment. And the last named segments are also optional - this is not clear in the example but consider them optional.

If I add the routes in the orders I listed them to the framework's `RouteCollection`, the first route will always match URLs like this: `/Home/Index/1`

Normally this is not a problem, but ASP.NET MVC's default model binder, when passing arguments to actions as parameters, requires the action's parameter to have the same name as the named segment in the route pattern.

So for an action `List` for example, where I want to pull a list of models to pass to the view, that accepts a page number as a parameter, I need to name that parameter **id**. Again normally, that is not a problem but I am detailed guy and I like my parameter names to give an indication what the parameter is used for.

But since the model binder kicks in after the routing system, I am out of luck. Or am I? Is there a way around this without writing my own model binder, or even worse, my own router?

In addition, and this can be considered a second related question, how do I ensure routing named segments are refactor safe?

Using `Url.Action`, for example, in my views is encouraged since they take routes into consideration. But to pass an argument when generating URLs using this method, one usually has to pass in an anonymous object, with a property whose name is also equal to the named segment.

So if I rename the named segment in my route, I literally have to go to all my views and rename that property as well. That does not sound optimal. So what's a clean way around this?

Comment: You would need something like the equivalent of `"/{id}".Where(id is integer)` or something like that. I'm pretty sure ASP.Net MVC doesn't support that. (good to know in my own minimalistic router that this functionality is useful though)

Comment: @Earlz I am pretty sure I can add a REGEX constraint to the route to make sure the named segment is an integer. But that won't make sense in my example since both `{id}` and `{page}` should/can be integers.

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand your problem now(my router still handles it, but won't work in MVC heh). So you're basically wanting for certain `action`s to resolve to page numbers and others to resolve to ids?

Comment: @Earlz Sorry for the late reply. Basically what I am asking is if there is a way for the default model binder to bind arguments in a route to parameters, regardless of their name. So for example, a route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}` can invoke and bind an action like `List(int? page)` and `Get(int? id)`. The framework would detect the route has an optional parameter and the action it resolves to also has an optional parameter. I don't have to explicitly give that parameter a name equal to the named segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the incoming request, the `RouteCollection` would pick the first `Route` where the regex logic matches.

Unfortunately, I do think that you are out of luck on such a high level view.

However, if you put in constraints of some kind, you may be able to wiggle your way into matching the second route.

Comment: Well I gave it a shot and waited to see if anyone else had an opinion. Looks like I am, like you say, out of luck on this. I'll keep exploring it more, but for now I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks for your help.